# Why isn't C# XML member documentation as "smart" as it is in VB.NET? Workarounds?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

One thing I've noticed as I'm migrating from VB.NET to C# is that the XML documentation for members is not as "smart" in C# as it is in VB.NET.  For one, it's lacking the intellisense when you're referencing other things.  For example, in the screen shots below, I have methods where I'm trying to reference `String` in the documentation.  With VB, I get the intellisense dropdown, and with C#, I don't.

[image]
[image]

Secondly, if I change the name of an argument, it doesn't produce a warning in C# as it does in VB.NET indicating that the documentation no longer matches the method signature:

[image]
[image]

This is particularly "dangerous" because it can lead to your API documentation being incorrect.

What accounts for these differences?  Is there a good reason why C# is limited in this way?  Or should I be looking at it differently or doing something in a different way?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but technically this is not a C# limitation, but well a limitation of VS if any.

Comment: I don't see how this question can have a good answer. Interesting trivia, but not quite the kind of thing that fits the format here.

Comment: If you turn on "Warnings as Errors" in your project settings, i think the second part of your question is answered. As for the first using `GhostDoc` to generate comments will be a good idea.

Comment: @david.pfx -- I disagree.  I'm looking for an answer to my question -- a workaround.  My purpose was not just to point out "trivia".

Comment: @Abhi -- Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried your suggestion of turning on "Warnings as Errors", but it didn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: @roryap: Did you check the checkbox `XML Documentation File`

Comment: @Abhi -- You nailed it.  In fact, I don't need to even turn on "Warnings as Errors".  If I check the box "XML Documentation File", they show up as warnings (which is what I originally wanted).  If you do it up as an answer, I'll give you credit (make sure to mention your suggestion of GhostDoc for the first part to make the answer complete).

Comment: You asked 3 'why' questions. These are not a good fit for SO. if you really want a workaround or a way to solve this problem you should edit your question to say so.

Comment: @david.pfx -- Not one of the questions is a "why" question.  Regardless, please post a link to a resource that explains to me why my questions are "not a good fit for SO", and I'll try to edit my question accordingly.  In the meantime, I'll have to rely, as I've done thus far, on resources like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, which, by my interpretation, allow for the questions as I've asked them.

Comment: If you're happy this question is as good as you can make it, I'll move on. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part using Ghost Doc would be a good idea.

As for the second the `XML Documentation` file checkbox needs to be checked in your project settings. All missing/incorrect XML comments would turn up as warnings.

If you absolutely want to make sure none of the warnings escape into production turning on `Treat warnings as errors` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You are just seeing a side-effect of the C# and VB.NET IDEs having been implemented by very different groups inside Microsoft.  Small groups is a survival strategy for any software company, Microsoft is not an exception.

And there's history behind these efforts, Visual Basic had strong IDE support long before C# ever came around.  The VB.NET team certainly got a running start on implementing theirs.  That isn't always an advantage, they were also stuck with having to make it similar to earlier IDEs to lessen the adoption shock that their prior VB customers had to go through.  Already a very significant one, VB.NET is pretty drastically different from earlier VB versions.  And otherwise not different from the one you are experiencing right now.

And they ultimately have different goals.  Very visible in your screenshot for example, the VB.NET IDE has the tabbed window with the "Common" and "All" tabs.  That has gotten a *lot* of VB.NET programmers in trouble, never figuring out that they need "All" sometimes.  C# doesn't have that, not the kind of language that ever aggressively hid anything.

We cannot help you paper over these differences, there are no settings for them.  You can file a feature request at [user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) but that's probably largely a waste of your effort.  Prior requests to change IntelliSense have consistently been met with "Thanks, we'll consider it for our next version!" without them being implemented.

You'll get used to it, all C# programmers did.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  Although it's frustrating dealing with the limitations of third-party software, I'm used to it, and, as you said, it's often a waste of effort to pursue a fix.

Comment: In this case, I was just hoping someone would point out something I didn't know about (as Abhi did with the XML documentation file check box) to get around the issue.